# Why am I getting these compilation errors in my Android application?

Tags: android

I have installed the Android SDK and now I am getting those errors:

> Description Resource Path Location Type error:
>   Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'icon' with value '@drawable/ic_launcher'). AndroidManifest.xml/Newbostton line 10 Android

and

> Description Resource Path Location Type R cannot be resolved to a variable
>   MainActivity.java   /Newbostton/src/com/Newboston/bhargav line 12

How can I resolve this?

Comment: import com.Newboston.bhargav.R; // I doubt it it will help. By the way, package name should be entirely lowercase.

Comment: And, please, provide lines where sdk found problems (10 and 12)

Answer (score 0):

Verify the syntax /res/values/strings.xml. Problem may not be in MainActivity.java

Check this for detail.
http://3thdev.blogspot.hk/2012/07/r-cannot-be-resolved-error.html

Answer (score 0):

Just do one thing if you are using eclipse, CTRL + SHIFT + I or CTRL + SHIFT + O, that will import all used imports in class